# Alternative way to load ringtone title in android

Tags: android, ringtone

I am developing an application where i need all the ringtone title and uri. I just need the title but not the Ringtone object. A well known way to get ringtone uri and title is following

```
rm = new RingtoneManager(getActivity());
rm.setType(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
Cursor cursor = rm.getCursor();
if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
   do{
     try{
        Uri uri= rm.getRingtoneUri(cursor.getPosition());
        Ringtone rtone = rm.getRingtone(cursor.getPosition());
        System.out.printf("URI: " + uri.toString());
        System.out.printf("Title: " + rtone.getTitle(this)); 
     }
     catch(Exception ee){}
     }while(cursor.moveToNext());
}
```

My problem is Ringtone object. It's costly to create Ringtone object each time. Ringtone object also create media player. So when i load all the list it's takes little bit time. I have also tested the code without creating the Ringtone object and it's fair enough.